# Check Status Code C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, http-status-codes

I need a way to run some if statements based on the status code that is returned after a request. For example, if a 400 error returns, I would like to redirect to a login page. I need some ideas on how to check the status code and include that information in an if statement. So something like

If () 
{

} 
else 
{

}

I just need the write-up to include in my if.

Comment: Are you using asp.net webforms ?

Comment: or are you writing an HTTP client?

Comment: Your question is way too vague.  The title alone could mean anything! Be more descriptive. Also include what you have tried, where you have looked and some examples of implementations. If not how the solution is implemented, then how you would attempt to use the solution if it had worked the way you wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by using the `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
 public static void GetPage(String url) 
    {
        try 
          { 
                // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
                // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
                if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                   Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}",
                                        myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
                // Releases the resources of the response.
                myHttpWebResponse.Close(); 

            } 
        catch(WebException e) 
           {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occured : {0}",e.Status); 
           }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe following Exception was raised : {0}",e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments mentioned, I'm not sure what type of project you are working on. However, in my MVC projects I handle this problem in the Web.config file with a few lines inside the system.web element such as:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```